# Shower whistles when running!

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, water, shower

I recently had my bathroom remodeled top to bottom. After installing new tub with new fixtures, when I pull tub diverter to use the shower, it whistles annoyingly and somewhat loud. This is a 2nd floor bathroom (the only bathroom) and has been ran with all ½" copper. I can sometimes play with the diverter and get it to go away or quiet down a little bit or not pulling the diverter all the way up seems to help but then I don't have as much pressure from my shower head.

I thought it was maybe the water saver so I tried removing it and also leaving it in but opened it up a little more with no success in stopping the whistling. Any ideas or help, please?

The house is older and previously had new copper run from the basement to 2nd floor and they ran it all in ½" which I know is a no no because it serves too many fixtures for that size piping when you include our kitchen on the way up but I don't know if this would cause whistling. I don't remember it making noise before the bathroom remodel.

Comment: Look for loose washers on faucets in the hot water line.

Comment: Looked and found nothing loose. Only happens at the shower when using shower and not when filling the bathtub

Answer (score 1):

Plumbing noise is caused by vibration due to turbulence. You'll need to track it down by process of elimination.

I'd start by running the water without the shower head. If that resolves the noise, install a different one. Most shower heads these days just use a rubber washer for a seal, so just snug it up lightly--say half a turn past hand tight.

If it's not the shower head you'll have to investigate the diverter valve. Pull the front hardware off and see if it has anti-scald adjustments which could be improperly set.

Also see if you learn anything by running just hot or cold separately.